# How many functions satisfy the following properties?

Tags: probability, functions

How many functions $f:\{a,b,c,d,e\} \rightarrow \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ satisfy the following two properties:

$f(a)+f(b)+f(c) = 8$

$f(d)+f(e) = 6$

Using the stars-and-bars method of sorting, I was able to identify that there are 8 "ones" that need to be sorted in the first equation, and 6 in the second. The first has 3 categories (a,b,c) and the second has 2.

Because $f(a)$, $f(b)$, $f(c)$ must each be at least $1$, we know that we have 5 remaining "ones" to sort out. We can solve this problem (5 remaining ones, 2 different categories, 3 already distributed ones) using $\binom{7}{2}$.

We can apply this same strategy for the second property, to get $\binom{5}{1}$. If we multiply these, we get $105$ different functions that satisfy these properties.

I am concerned that some of these $105$ are not actually viable since there must be some combination of function that overlaps the available numbers, i.e., some kind of intersection that needs to be subtracted? How would one go about doing this?

Comment: What kind of restrictions do you propose to exist?

Comment: None that are outrightly stated in the problem itself. I'm just a little confused - since the five numbers must be split between the 5 variables, we can't have functions say, 1+3+4=8;, 1+5=6, since it would re-use 1, right? However $\binom{7}{2}$ simply finds 21 functions for the FIRST property, and $\binom{5}{1}$ finds 5 functions for the SECOND property, but combining them into 105 functions will probably have some overlap, right?

Comment: If you really doubt yourself that much... then just rephrase your approach to make no mention of stars-and-bars and instead use casework.  It will be more tedious, but it will arrive at the same conclusion.  Break into cases based on the value of $f(a)$.  If $f(a)=1$ then $f(b)$ could be any of $2,3,4,5$.  Having then picked the value of $f(b)$ will force $f(c)$ to be $8-f(a)-f(b)$ in order to make them sum to $8$.  Continue in this fashion to tangibly see all $\binom{7}{2}$ possible ways to distribute the values for $f(a),f(b),f(c)$ and apply multiplication principle for how to choose for d,e

Comment: @JMoravitz, Okay! I actually just realized it should be $\binom{7}{2}$ but in my calculation for 175 I think I used $\binom{7}{3}$. Thank you, though!

Comment: I think that $7\choose 2$ comprises some configurations where a letter is mapped to $6$, which is forbidden. It should be ${7\choose 2}-3$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, wouldn't $\binom{7}{2}$ just show ways of choosing $2$ items from $7$ - or $5$ items from $7$, excluding two possible items (6 and 7).

Comment: Whatever number the arithmetic happens to provide is fine.  Now.... as for "*we can't have functions say, $1+3+4=8;,1+5=6$ since it would re-use $1$, right?*"  No... you can absolutely reuse $1$.  It asked for how many functions.  It did *not* ask for how many *bijective* functions.  In fact, you should be able to convince yourself that there *must* be some number repeated somewhere since otherwise $f((a)+f(b)+f(c))+(f(d)+f(e))=8+6=14\neq 1+2+3+4+5=15$

Comment: @JMoravitz, okay - that explanation about bijectivity makes a ton of sense. Thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: @ArnaudMortier good catch.  Yes, that would be a slight flaw in the arithmetic above.

Comment: $7\choose 2$ chooses the position of two bars amongst $7$ placeholders, and the other $5$ are your stars, but $a$, $b$, $c$ all have one star already, they can't take five more.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Okay, that makes sense. In that case, would I do ($\binom{7}{2} - 3$) $\times$ ($\binom{5}{1} - 2$) for the final answer?

Comment: Wait, never mind - the second property is fine without subtracting $2$ since there is no way they would go over $5$. Thank you!

Comment: Use parentheses.  And no, it would be $(\binom{7}{2}-3)\times\binom{5}{1}$.  No such correction needs to be made for the second part.  You can see yourself all five of the pairs they could make (1,5),(2,4),...(5,1)

Comment: @JMoravitz Yup I just realized that!! Thank you so much for your help and clear explanations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $ \{a,b,c \}$ can be mapped onto the sets $\{1,2,5\},\{1,3,4\},\{2,2,4\},\{2,3,3\}$ in respectively $6,6,3,3$ ways. ($18$ in total).

The set $\{d,e\}$ can be mapped onto the sets $\{1,5\},\{2,4\},\{3,3\}$ in respectively $2,2,1$ ways. ($5$ in total).

So there are $18 \times 5= \color{red}{90}$ possible functions.